# Eloquent: How to get data from three related tables?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get all `orders` associated with a `Product` and an `Event`.

Must params:

- `order.date == event.date`, and
- `order.order_product_id == event.product_id`

Here are my code:

**Product:** `[id, name]`.

```
class Product    

// get Product related events
public function events()
{
   $this->hasMany(Order::class)
}

// get Product related orders
public function orders()
{
   $this->hasMany(Event::class)
}
```

**Event:** `[id, product_id, date]`

```
class Event

// get related Product
public function product()
{
   $this->belognsTo(Product::class)
}
```

**Order:** `[id, date, order_product_id]`

```
public function product()
{
   $this->belognsTo(Product::class,'order_product_id')
}

// I Want to get all Events, where present Product with 'order_product_id'
public function scheduled()
{
   $this->hasMany(Product::class,'order_product_id', 'product_id')
}
```

---

**In summary:**

If I have an `Event` with the `id=9`, how do get the number of orders of the same product for associated to this event.

Answer (score 2):

To count how many orders with the same product present in orders table you can use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models):

```
$eventId = 9;
$product = Product::whereHas('events', function($q) use ($eventId ){
               $q->where('id', $eventId);
           })
           ->withCount('orders')
           ->get();
```

This code will return `Product` with additional attribute `orders_count`.

Another way is to use simple queries:

```
$productId = Event::where('id', 9)->first()->id;
$ordersCount = Order::where('order_product_id', $productId)->count();
```

Also, you have an error in relations. `orders()` pointed to `Event` class and `events()` pointed to `Order`.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to get orders as objects instead orders_count what I should to do? S Novym godom:)

Comment: If you want to get objects, just use `with()` instead of `withCount()`. Happy New Year. )

Comment: Relations should be pointed to appropriate classes. If you see `filteredProducts` relation, it should be pointed to `Product`, but not to `User` or something.

Comment: Maybe I did not properly asked. But i found other solution, look below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

Add to Event model class two methods:

```
public function scheduledOrders()
{
    return $this->orders()->whereHas('product', function ($q) {
        $q->whereHas('scheduled', function ($q) {
            $q->whereRaw("events_table.date = orders_table.date")->where('id',$this->id);
        });
    })->get();
}

public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'order_product_id', 'product_id');
}
```

And when we get concrete Event, we can look all related orders with same date and product_id.

```
$scheduledOrders = Event::find(14)->scheduledOrders();
```

scheduledOrders() method will return related Orders [Collection] with the same date and product_id which has this Event.